# What is the difference between "params" and "array parameter" and when should it be used?

Tags: c#

What is the exact difference between these two methods? When to use "params" and when to use array parameters? A reply would be greatly appreciated.

```
// passing array to a method
class Program
{
    static void printarray(int[] newarray)
    {
        int i,sum=0;
        Console.Write("\n\nYou entered:\t");
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}\t", newarray[i]);
            sum = sum + newarray[i];
        }
        Console.Write("\n\nAnd sum of all value is:\t{0}", sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[4];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter number:\t");
            arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        // passing array as argument
        Program.printarray(arr);
        }
    }
}
//using parameter arrays
public class MyClass
{
public static void UseParams(params int[] list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
static void Main()
{ 
    UseParams(1, 2, 3, 4);
    int[] myIntArray = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    UseParams(myIntArray);      
}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `params` you can pass *zero* or more arguments, but with arrays, you have to prodive that argument if it's not *optional*.For example you can call this method without passing any argument and args will be empty:

```
public void Foo(params int[] args) { }

Foo(); // no compile-time error, args will be empty
```

But if you use an array:

```
public void Foo(int[] args) { }

Foo(); // error: No overload for 'Foo' takes 0 arguments
```

Otherwise there is not much difference between two. `params` is just a syntactic sugar.

Comment: to get no error with parameter use it like::  public void Foo(int[] args = null) { }

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Selman's answer, There are some obvious but minor limitations when using `params`:

According to [MS C# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)

> No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a method declaration.

This is because the compiler would have hard time identifying which parameter belongs to which.
The compiler will also complain if you have normal argument before the `params`

> `params` parameter must be the last in a formal parameter list.

For example this would not be allowed:

```
public void Foo(params int[] args,int value) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous two answers. If we have a method

`calculate(params int[] b)`

Then it can be invoked with `calculate(1,2,3)`

Now if you would have used integer array `calculate(int[] b)`. You won't be able to call the function like this `calculate(1,2,3)`.

Comment: Oh so you mean if I use an integer array, I have to pass an array as a parameter right?

Answer (score 0):

1. `Arrays` need to pass at least 1 argument to method to work.
2. `params` can work without arguments in method.
3. No additional parameters are allowed after the `params` keyword in a method declaration, and only one `params` keyword is allowed in a method declaration.

   ```
        static int test(params string[] test1)
    {
        return test1.Length;
    }
   ```

- Calling the method with some arguments.

`Console.WriteLine($"\"params\" got {test("Japan", "Germany", "Maldives")} strings in the row.");  // returns 3`

- Calling the method with no argument. Arrays can't do.

`Console.WriteLine($"\"params\" got {test()} strings in the row.");  // returns 0`