# Why can't I have two method signatures with the only difference being the "params" keyword for the array parameter?

Tags: c#, params-keyword

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(SomeType[] elements)
    {
        
    }
    public SomeClass(params SomeType[] elements)
    {
        
    }
}
```

I printed this code and got [CS0111](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0111) error. I'm surprised, are `SomeType[] elements` and `params SomeType[] elements` the same arguments?

Comment: Both constructors have the same signature. `params` keyword does not change method signature.

Comment: `params` is not the part of the signature of the function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375707/what-is-the-difference-between-params-and-array-parameter-and-when-should-it

Comment: Note that `params` is just a metadata keyword for the C# compiler and has no bearing on the method signature nor on the compilation of the method itself. Basically, `params` is just an instruction for the compiler regarding **call sites** (i.e. callers) of this method to translate a method call in source code like `SomeFooWithParams(1, 2, 3, 4)` into `SomeFooWithParams(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 })` (for simplicity, lets ignore right now any other non-params parameters a method might declare...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two is that one requires a single concrete array, while the other **also** allows it to be called with individual items such as

```
SomeClass("Alpha", "Omega", "Gamma")
```

Choose the `params` one if you need to call it as above and delete the other.

#### Why?

The error speaks to the fact that both are, to the compiler, the same signature `SomeType[]` hence the error.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `params` does not make the parameter into a different type. Both translate to an array of SomeType.